# Getting error in the contract code "please check your gas amount"

Tags: solidity, truffle, ganache

I am getting this error:

> Error: The contract code couldn't be stored, please check your gas
>   amount.

This is when I am importing one extra contract with the name of `TimedCrowdsale` from OpenZeppelin. There was no error earlier when I imported and used `Crowdsale`, `MintedCrowdsale` and `CappedCrowdsale` from openzeppelin.

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange ajay! What gas value did you put in your truffle configuration file?

Comment: hi paul i changed the the gas value to 7492052.still its showing the same message .when i remove the timedtoken the contract runs properly

Answer (score 1):

That's the thing with putting more and more code in your contract, in this case, by means of inheriting OpenZeppelin awesomely crafted ready solutions: your byte code size grows accordingly.

Here are some ways to check and overcome the problem:

- check if you really need everything you inherit
- put a higher `gasLimit` to your `truffle.js` config, try `gas: 7492052`, which is higher than the value in Truffle's defaults, and than in Rinkeby testnet.
- use [optimizer settings](https://truffleframework.com/docs/truffle/reference/configuration#solidity-compiler-configuration) to make bytecode slimmer and deploy cheaper
- if the above doesn't let you deploy and at least see your actual deploy cost, try commenting some functionality out and trying local deploy without something
- if the steps above show that you really need this much code and more, you can chop it in parts and deploy some of it as [libraries](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.24/contracts.html#libraries) or as separated contracts, one addressing another, depending on what fits you best.

Hope it helps, that's basically my own trial-and-error conspectus on the matter.