# Increase MaxCodeSize in ethereum private network

Tags: go-ethereum

Is there anyway to increase the MaxCodeSize = 24576 ? I am getting below error while deploying the contract

DEBUG[09-18|11:33:43.885] VM returned with error err=evm: max code size exceeded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's [hardcoded](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/params/protocol_params.go#L61) in `go-ethereum`, see why in [eip-170](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-170.md).

In theory, you can change the value in the source code, build your own `geth`, run your private dev environment with it and enjoy a higher code size limit value. But you can't change this value neither in Mainnet nor in any public testnet, so it's best to cope with it differently.

Check this [answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/58608/11501) to a related question.